# Loop through one list and append items to a group of three lists, one after the other

Tags: python

I'm looping through a csv.reader() object to access each of the 18 lines (each some info about soccer players) in the original CSV file, and then needing to make up three new teams of 6 from these entries. It's tying my brain in a knot; is there a way to accomplish this using a for loop? Like, how can I loop through one list, then append the first item looped through to team1, the second item looped to team2, and so on? I've gotten as far as using random.choice() from a list of the three lists, but using if and while statements to to keep each list down to 6 entries keeps giving me weird results.

Don't know how much it will help but here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import random

team1 = []
team2 = []
team3 = []

teamlists = [team1, team2, team3]

with open('soccer_players.csv') as csv_file:
    player_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for line in player_reader:
        rando = random.choice(teamlists)
        rando.append(line)
        # Need to fill up team1, team2, team3 equally.
```

Here is the CSV file I'm working with:

```
Name,Height (inches),Soccer Experience,Guardian Name(s)
Joe Smith,42,YES,Jim and Jan Smith
Jill Tanner,36,YES,Clara Tanner
Bill Bon,43,YES,Sara and Jenny Bon
Eva Gordon,45,NO,Wendy and Mike Gordon
Matt Gill,40,NO,Charles and Sylvia Gill
Kimmy Stein,41,NO,Bill and Hillary Stein
Sammy Adams,45,NO,Jeff Adams
Karl Saygan,42,YES,Heather Bledsoe
Suzane Greenberg,44,YES,Henrietta Dumas
Sal Dali,41,NO,Gala Dali
Joe Kavalier,39,NO,Sam and Elaine Kavalier
Ben Finkelstein,44,NO,Aaron and Jill Finkelstein
Diego Soto,41,YES,Robin and Sarika Soto
Chloe Alaska,47,NO,David and Jamie Alaska
Arnold Willis,43,NO,Claire Willis
Phillip Helm,44,YES,Thomas Helm and Eva Jones
Les Clay,42,YES,Wynonna Brown
Herschel Krustofski,45,YES,Hyman and Rachel Krustofski
```

Comment: how many columns have you got in your csv file? what do you expect `i` to be? `rando.append(line[0])` would probably work if there's only one.

Comment: Are you just trying t randomly assign these 18 players represented by rows in your csv to 3 different teams?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Do you can share csv file?

Comment: @nicecore, you'd better use `@username` syntax, otherwise no user will be notified of your comment.

Comment: What are the csv column names @nicecore?

Comment: @DanIonescu, I edited the entry to include the CSV file per julian salas' request

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oops, I did a bit of cutting and pasting from the larger project I'm working on to help visualize what I'm trying to do and 'i' is from something else. I guess 'i' should be 'line'. There are 4 columns in the CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a loop to create the teams like you're trying to do.

Instead, if you first read all the players into a list, shuffle that list, then the team lists can be created simply by slicing it up into thirds. This approach would also make it relatively easy to divide the shuffled players list into a different number of teams.

The following illustrates how this could be done:

```
import csv
import random

with open('soccer_players.csv') as csv_file:
    next(csv_file)  # skip header row
    players = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')]

random.shuffle(players)
team1, team2, team3 = [players[i::3] for i in range(3)]

# display results
for i, team in enumerate([team1, team2, team3], 1):
    print('team{}: {}'.format(i, team))
```

Output:

```
team1: ['Chloe Alaska', 'Ben Finkelstein', 'Phillip Helm', 'Joe Smith', 'Kimmy Stein', 'Arnold Willis']
team2: ['Matt Gill', 'Jill Tanner', 'Diego Soto', 'Les Clay', 'Herschel Krustofski', 'Bill Bon']
team3: ['Joe Kavalier', 'Karl Saygan', 'Eva Gordon', 'Sammy Adams', 'Sal Dali', 'Suzane Greenberg']
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a title line in your input file, so you have to skip it.

Then, first idea would be to just pick the first column (the name) to append to the randomly selected list chosen with `random.choice(teamlists)`

But it may not distribute the values equally like this, since such or such sub-list may be chosen more frequently than others.

To get a guaranteed even distribution (provided that the list of names is dividable by 3 of course), I would do this:

```
teams = [[] for _ in range(3)]

with open('soccer_players.csv') as csv_file:
    player_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(player_reader) # skip title line
    names = [line[0] for line in player_reader]
    random.shuffle(names)
    for i,n in enumerate(names):
        teams[i%len(teams)].append(n)
```

`names` is the list of player names. use `random.shuffle` to change order randomly. Then use a simple loop with modulo to dispatch the values.

Answer (score 0):

This script will create a dictionary with the keys numbers ( from 0 to n where n is the last team ) and values a list of names:

I've not used the random approach because it can create slightly disbalanced lists

```
import csv

team1 = []
team2 = []
team3 = []

teamlists = [team1, team2, team3]
with open('/home/dan/Downloads/test.csv') as csv_file:
    next(csv_file) # to skip header
    player_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    team_index = 0
    for line in player_reader:
        current_list_number = team_index % 3
        teamlists[current_list_number].append(line[0])
        team_index += 1

print teamlists
# will output:
# [['Joe Smith', 'Eva Gordon', 'Sammy Adams', 'Sal Dali', 'Diego Soto', 'Phillip Helm'], ['Jill Tanner', 'Matt Gill', 'Karl Saygan', 'Joe Kavalier', 'Chloe Alaska', 'Les Clay'], ['Bill Bon', 'Kimmy Stein', 'Suzane Greenberg', 'Ben Finkelstein', 'Arnold Willis', 'Herschel Krustofski']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill 3 lists equally (provided csv has data that's divisible by 3) as follows,

```
import csv
import random

team1 = []
team2 = []
team3 = []

teamlists = [team1, team2, team3]

with open('soccer_players.csv') as csv_file:
    player_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(player_reader, None)  # skip the headers


    for idx,line in enumerate(player_reader):
        if idx % 3 == 0:
            team1.append(line)
        elif idx % 3 == 1:
            team2.append(line)
        if idx % 3 == 2:
            team3.append(line)

print "team1 = {}".format(team1)
print "----------------------------------------"
print "team2 = {}".format(team2)
print "----------------------------------------"
print "team3 = {}".format(team3)
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
team1 = [['Joe Smith', '42', 'YES', 'Jim and Jan Smith'], ['Eva Gordon', '45', 'NO', 'Wendy and Mike Gordon'], ['Sammy Adams', '45', 'NO', 'Jeff Adams'], ['Sal Dali', '41', 'NO', 'Gala Dali'], ['Diego Soto', '41', 'YES', 'Robin and Sarika Soto'], ['Phillip Helm', '44', 'YES', 'Thomas Helm and Eva Jones']]
----------------------------------------
team2 = [['Jill Tanner', '36', 'YES', 'Clara Tanner'], ['Matt Gill', '40', 'NO', 'Charles and Sylvia Gill'], ['Karl Saygan', '42', 'YES', 'Heather Bledsoe'], ['Joe Kavalier', '39', 'NO', 'Sam and Elaine Kavalier'], ['Chloe Alaska', '47', 'NO', 'David and Jamie Alaska'], ['Les Clay', '42', 'YES', 'Wynonna Brown']]
----------------------------------------
team3 = [['Bill Bon', '43', 'YES', 'Sara and Jenny Bon'], ['Kimmy Stein', '41', 'NO', 'Bill and Hillary Stein'], ['Suzane Greenberg', '44', 'YES', 'Henrietta Dumas'], ['Ben Finkelstein', '44', 'NO', 'Aaron and Jill Finkelstein'], ['Arnold Willis', '43', 'NO', 'Claire Willis'], ['Herschel Krustofski', '45', 'YES', 'Hyman and Rachel Krustofski']]
>>> len(team1)
6
>>> len(team2)
6
>>> len(team3)
6
```